# Regular expression not matching subexpression when optional

Tags: php, regex

I'm matching against an HTML string to return the first HTML element and check whether it has a class attribute.  My test HTML string is:

```
<h3 class="class-name">Blah blah</h3>
```

The following regex:

```
/^<[^>]+(?:class=['\"]([^\"]+)['\"])[^>]*>/
```

Returns the following matches:

```
[0] = <h3 class="class-name">
[1] = class-name
```

However, as soon as I make the "class" subexpression optional:

```
/^<[^>]+(?:class=['\"]([^\"]+)['\"])?[^>]*>/
```

I loose the second "class-name" match:

```
[0] = <h3 class="class-name">
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ridgerunner has correctly analyzed your problem. To see why even the lazy version fails:

```
 <h3 class="class-name">Blah blah</h3>
^<                               # matches until the first <           --> OK
  [^>]+?                         # matches nothing by default          --> OK
  (?:class=['\"]([^\"]+)['\"])?  # doesn't match here, but is optional --> OK
  [^>]*                          # matches until the end of the tag    --> OK
                       >         # matches the closing >               --> Match!
```

The official solution is, of course, to use an HTML parser. But in your case, you can solve the problem by extending the scope of the optional group:

```
^<(?:[^>]*class=['\"]([^\"]+)['\"])?[^>]*>
```

Now the `(?:...)` group first tries all positions for a valid match.

Comment: Thanks @Tim, that clarified things quite a bit.  I've got it working now.  And I'll look into an HTML parser as well....

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. What is happening is the first: `[^>]+` greedily matches up to the closing `>`. It then tries to match: `(?:class...)?` which fails. However since this and the `[^>]*` which follows can both match nothing at all, the closing `>` is matched and a successful match is declared (with nothing captured).

What is interesting is that this *"nothing in capture group one"* behavior happens even when the first greedy expression is made lazy: `[^>]+?`.

But what you are *really* doing wrong is attempting to parse HTML with regex!

### Additional

To illustrate why using regex to parse HTML is not such a great idea, consider the following peculiarities of valid HTML markup:

- Attribute values may be double quoted, and may contain single quotes and angle brackets, e.g. `<b title="That's <i>entertainment!</i>">bold stuff</b>`. The title attribute value here contains text that looks like a tag but is not.
- Attribute values may be single quoted, and may contain double quotes and angle brackets, e.g. `<b title='<i class="this is not a class">is this inside an I element? NO!</i>'>bold stuff</b>`.
- Attribute values may be non quoted, e.g. `<b class=myclass>bold stuff</b>`
- Attribute values are optional, e.g. `<option selected>`

There are many other aspects of HTML markup that can trip up a regex (see caveats below), but lets just consider the above aspects first.

### A similar (but slightly more complex) question:

Lets say that in addition to the CLASS attribute value, you also wish to capture the element name and the values of the ID and TITLE attributes as well. All three attributes are optional. The tag name will always be captured in `$1`, and If any of the CLASS, ID or TITLE attribute values exist, they will be captured in `$2`, `$3` and `$4` respectively. These attributes may appear in any order and there may be any number of other attributes mixed in as well, each with or without values, and the values may be double quoted, single quoted or non-quoted.

This *can* be (imperfectly) accomplished (see caveats below) with a Perl/PHP/PCRE regular expression, but its quite long and complex and requires use of the `(?|...|...)` *branch reset* construct. Here it is:

```php
<?php
// Match HTML start tags and print CLASS, ID and TITLE attributes.
//   Note that this method is not 100% reliable and can easily fail.
function printTagAttributes($text) {
    $re = '%# Match HTML start tags. Capture CLASS, ID and TITLE values.
        <                   # Opening < of start tag.
        (\w+)               # $1: Element name.
        (?:                 # Group for zero or more attributes.
          \s+               # Required whitespace before attribute.
          (?:               # Group for attribute alternatives.
            class\s*=\s*    # Match any CLASS attribute value in $2.
            (?|             # Branch reset group for $2: value.
              "([^"]*)"     # $2.1: Double quoted value or,
            | \'([^\']*)\'  # $2.2: Single quoted value or,
            | ([\w\-.:]+)   # $2.3: Non quoted value.
            )               # End branch reset group.
          | id\s*=\s*       # Match any ID attribute value in $3.
            (?|             # Branch reset group for $3: value.
              "([^"]*)"     # $3.1: Double quoted value or,
            | \'([^\']*)\'  # $3.2: Single quoted value or,
            | ([\w\-.:]+)   # $3.3: Non quoted value.
            )               # End branch reset group.
          | title\s*=\s*    # Match any TITLE attribute value in $4.
            (?|             # Branch reset group for $4: value.
              "([^"]*)"     # $4.1: Double quoted value or,
            | \'([^\']*)\'  # $4.2: Single quoted value or,
            | ([\w\-.:]+)   # $4.3: Non quoted value.
            )               # End branch reset group.
          | [\w\-.:]+       # or match any other attribute.
            (?:             # Group for optional attrib value.
              \s*=\s*       # Name and value separated by =
              (?:           # Group for attrib value alternatives.
                "[^"]*"     # Either Double quoted value,
              | \'[^\']*\'  # or single quoted value,
              | [\w\-.:]+   # or non quoted value.
              )             # End group of attrib value alts.
            )?              # Attribute value is optional.
          )                 # End group of attribute alternatives.
        )*                  # Zero or more attributes.
        \s*                 # Optional whitespace before close >
        /?                  # Match "empty elements" too.
        >                   # Closing > of start tag.
        %ix';
    $elementcount = preg_match_all($re, $text, $matches);
    if ($elementcount) {
        printf("%d HTML start tags found:\n", $elementcount);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $elementcount; ++$i) {
            printf("Tag[%d] = \"%s\"\n", $i + 1, $matches[1][$i]);
            // Print CLASS attribute from capture group $2
            if (isset($matches[2][$i]) && $matches[2][$i]) {
                printf("\tCLASS  = {%s}\n", $matches[2][$i]);
            } else {
                printf("\tTag has no CLASS attribute.\n");
            }
            // Print ID attribute from capture group $3
            if (isset($matches[3][$i]) && $matches[3][$i]) {
                printf("\tID     = {%s}\n", $matches[3][$i]);
            } else {
                printf("\tTag has no ID attribute.\n");
            }
            // Print TITLE attribute from capture group $4
            if (isset($matches[4][$i]) && $matches[4][$i]) {
                printf("\tTITLE  = {%s}\n", $matches[4][$i]);
            } else {
                printf("\tTag has no TITLE attribute.\n");
            }
        }
    } else {
        printf("No HTML start tags found.\n");
    }
}

$data = file_get_contents('testdata.html');
printTagAttributes($data);
?>
```

Here is a valid `HTML 4.01 STRICT` test file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test printTagAttributes()</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="H1 CLASS" id="H1_ID" title="H1 TITLE">
    Test printTagAttributes()
</h1>
<h3 class="class-name">Blah blah</h3>
<p title="P1 TITLE" id="P1_ID" class="P1 CLASS" >
  Paragraph 1 has attributes in reverses order.
</p>
<p class=P2_CLASS id=P2_ID title=P2_TITLE>
  Paragraph 2 has attributes specified with unquoted values.
</p>
<!-- StackOverflow highlighter chokes on the following title -->
<p title='This title has <i>an embedded "non-tag"</i>!'>
  Paragraph 3 has a TITLE attribute value containing
  both double quotes and angle brackets. This one will
  trip up many regexes!
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Output when the above test file is run through the script:

```py
#use python raw string to preserve spacing...
output=r'''
10 HTML start tags found:
Tag[1] = "html"
        Tag has no CLASS attribute.
        Tag has no ID attribute.
        Tag has no TITLE attribute.
Tag[2] = "head"
        Tag has no CLASS attribute.
        Tag has no ID attribute.
        Tag has no TITLE attribute.
Tag[3] = "title"
        Tag has no CLASS attribute.
        Tag has no ID attribute.
        Tag has no TITLE attribute.
Tag[4] = "meta"
        Tag has no CLASS attribute.
        Tag has no ID attribute.
        Tag has no TITLE attribute.
Tag[5] = "body"
        Tag has no CLASS attribute.
        Tag has no ID attribute.
        Tag has no TITLE attribute.
Tag[6] = "h1"
        CLASS  = {H1 CLASS}
        ID     = {H1_ID}
        TITLE  = {H1 TITLE}
Tag[7] = "h3"
        CLASS  = {class-name}
        Tag has no ID attribute.
        Tag has no TITLE attribute.
Tag[8] = "p"
        CLASS  = {P1 CLASS}
        ID     = {P1_ID}
        TITLE  = {P1 TITLE}
Tag[9] = "p"
        CLASS  = {P2_CLASS}
        ID     = {P2_ID}
        TITLE  = {P2_TITLE}
Tag[10] = "p"
        Tag has no CLASS attribute.
        Tag has no ID attribute.
        TITLE  = {This title has <i>an embedded "non-tag"</i>!}
'''
```

### Caveats:

This regex which attempts to match a start tag does not take into consideration the full complexities of the (non-regular) HTML markup language. There are *many* ways for it to be tripped up: e.g. CDATA sections, comments, scripts and styles can all cause problems. Although there *are* cases where it is appropriate to use regex with HTML, these are few and far between.

Comment: Yeah, I see now that the first + should be lazy, but as you said, still not working :(  Also, I'm actually parsing a string (WordPress post content) for HTML, not an actual HTML document, if that makes a difference.  If there is a better method to accomplish what I'm trying to do, I'd love to hear it.